# GZIP is enabled but it is not compressing one CSS file

Tags: css, server, gzip, cpanel

I have enabled GZIP in cPanel (Software > Optimize Website).  It's set to "Compress All Content".  GTmetrix speed test reports that one CSS file is not being compressed:

https://www.swphotovideo.com.au/wp-content/cache/min/1/2affb9ab843ac1d569fdadbf67636031.css

Any idea why this might?  It's quite large (1mb~) so I'd like to sort it out.  GZIP seems to be working for everything else, but this file.

Answer (score 0):

We use GZIP to compress files so that Websites speed will become fast. As your problem shows you are able to compress all other files but not able to compress "CSS" files.
First of all, you should check your .htaccess file and check whether "TEXT/CSS" is there under "mod_deflate" or not.

```
# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP
```

Also, to speed up your WordPress website you can use mod_expires to have Browser cache in WordPress which will speed up your website. 
You can refer this article to speed up your WordPress application.
https://hoststud.com/resources/tips-to-leverage-browser-caching-in-wordpress.156/

Or, you should ask your hosting provider regarding this issue.